# Преобразование медалей в репутацию

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Почему бы не добавить функцию преобразования медалей в репутацию? Главное на stackoverflow — репутация, ведь так? (*Второстепенное надо было написать*) При наборе определённого количества репутации участнику выдаётся новая возможность. За медали же участники не получают репутацию. При этом некоторые медали можно получать несколько раз, только вот в итоге пропадает некий интерес к выполнению заданий. А если добавить возможность преобразования медалей в репутацию с последующим удалением этой медали (чтоб участник повторно желал получить её, чтобы потом опять за неё получить вознаграждение), то может повыситься активность в помощи от новичков.

Comment: я голосую против. Медали дают плюшки сами по себе (например золотой знак) либо являются показателем активности пользователя (картточка на выборах). Конвертация в обезличенную репутацию не имеет смысла. Так же медали (как и достижения в играх) показывают участнику что делать хорошо, а цвет медали показывает насколько тяжело это делать...

Comment: `Главное на stackoverflow репутация,ведь так ?` - главное на *stackoverflow* — **ЗНАНИЯ**. Если ты пришел только за репутацией - то ты не туда пришёл

Comment: `пропадает некий интерес к выполнению заданий.` - это не игра с квестами, так, на секундочку

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я думаю тут имелось в виду что репутацией меряться удобнее чем медальками. Многие любят показывать всем что они чего-то добились.

Comment: pavel, получить бейдж "Фанатик" - не тяжело :) Вот если бы было _заходить на сайт в течении 365 дней подряд_ , вот это я понимаю. Алексей-Шиманский,правильное напоминание,но харэ тыкать) Используйте "вы". Это не игра с квестами, это просто - игра, с помощью которой улучшается сайт. Вы хотите сказать,что _медали_ не атрибут игры, так на секундочку ? :)

Comment: "Главное на stackoverflow — репутация, ведь так?" Грустно...

Comment: @Suvitruf, от чего вам грустно? Знания конечно важнее, но вот после него на сайте идёт репутация, иначе зачем она? Если бы на сайте не было репутации,вы занимались бы правками ? Вы отвечали бы на вопросы более развёрнуто новичкам?

Comment: @stackflow репутация - не самоцель, это приятный бонус.

Comment: @Suvitruf,а чем именно этот бонус вам приятен ?

Comment: @stackflow показывает мой вклад. Небольшой индикатор того, что мои ответы кому-то полезны.

Answer (score 10):

Во-первых, не  надо забывать, что наш сайт имеет только те возможности, которые уже реализованы в движке "большого" so. Так что если вам хочется такую фичу – лучше бы подымать тему на "их" мете.

Во-вторых, из теории игр и институциональной экономики я знаю, что правила игры очень сильно определяют её механику, чуть тронь – и можно легко разбалансировать систему. Есть даже целая профессия такая – геймдизайнер, их отдельно учат тому, как сделать интересный геймплей. Поэтому я бы рекомендовал следовать принципу "Семь раз отмерь – один отрежь" и начал с вопроса "какую цель мы преследуем?" Какой-то конкретной цели я в вашем посте не увидел, это было "пуркуа бы и не па?" и "лично мне пожалуй было бы так интереснее". Мгм, а подумать о других участниках, посмотреть кого больше?

В-третьих, как по мне текущая сложившаяся модель репутации вполне адекватна.

Репутация – выдаётся ТОЛЬКО за вклад в вопросы/ответы, это её назначение. Конвертировать «Фанатика» (сто дней подряд заходил на сайт) в репутацию – просто нонсенс.

Вы считаете, что медали – это скучно? А я напротив считаю, что как раз медали – это нескучно. Репутация линейна: больше-меньше, нет градации по уровням. А вот как раз медали расширяют эту модель: фактически, каждая медаль – это ещё одна линейка репутации. Например, есть линейка репутаций "проверка очередей" и у кого-то в ней сто проверок, а у кого-то тысяча: можно провести аналогию между числом проверок и числом баллов репутации. По знакам/медалькам видно «специализацию» участника, что ему интереснее в сообществе (посмотрите на группировку медалей: вопросы - ответы - участие - метки - модерация). Кому-то неинтересны конкурсы, кто-то разгребает очереди проверок. Знаки интереснее тем, что в них часто бывает градация на бронзу-серебро-золото: в отличие от репутации, которая является всего лишь числом без разделения на уровни.

Однообразие и интерес – противоположные понятия, поэтому со знаками интереснее. Не вижу смысла в том, чтобы разрешать конвертацию в репутацию: это просто разные вещи.

Comment: Подумал, что очереди проверок работают как ежедневные квесты в некоторых MMORPG, а знаки за метки, правки и тревоги — как фарм мобов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin собираю пати из 5 человек на фарм "закрытие вопросов", условия: 2к+ репутация, 50 голосов на сегодня, адекватность. Наличие золотых молотков приветствуется.

Comment: @pavel мне нечестно будет, у меня God Mode и бесконечные патроны. :)

Comment: `пуркуа бы и не па?` - ??? Джклм,джклм?)

Comment: @pavel [Чат закрывашек](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32210/) сдох, есть силы реанимировать? Нонче модно кидать в основной чат -- там всегда есть дежурные.

Comment: Репутация всё же бьется на уровни. Описаны они на [странице привилегий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).